# Не выводится результат условия if . Задача

Tags: php, if

Изучаю основы пхп. Попалась такая задача. Возникла трудность. Если попадается високосный год, то сообщение не выводится на экран. Подскажите ошибку в коде.  Сама задача :"В переменной $year хранится год. Определите, является ли он високосным
 (в таком году есть 29 февраля). Год будет високосным в двух случаях: либо он делится на 4, но при этом не делится на 100, либо делится на 400. Так, годы 1700, 1800 и 1900 не являются високосными, так как они делятся на 100 и не делятся на 400. Годы 1600 и 2000 - високосные, так как они делятся на 400."

```
<?php 
$year = 2008;

if ($year % 4 == 0 && $year % 100 != 0) {
    if ($year % 400 == 0){
        echo 'високосный';
    }
}else echo 'невисокосный';
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правильно составили условие "либо". 
Вот так правильно:

```
$year = 2008;

if (($year % 4 == 0 && $year % 100 != 0) || $year % 400 == 0) {
     echo 'високосный';
 } else {
     echo 'невисокосный' 
 };
```